# ScrollView smoothScrollTo does nothing when screen off

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-event

I have this problem that when the device screen is turned off, and my `Timer`  triggers, I call `ScrollView` method `smoothScrollTo`.

However it does nothing, I am not getting `onScrollChanged`callbacks at all. Is there any solution or workaround for this?

Thanks.

Comment: aren't you onPaused when the screen goes of ? in which case, onResume is called, and you may do your scrolling then.

Comment: just want to know, if your screen is off , then no visual effect needed, why do you want to call that method to scroll your view ?

Comment: The timer triggers no matter if the screen is on or off. So that's why smoothScrollTo, so if the screen is on user can see the smooth scroll there.

Comment: Relying in onResume here is an awful option, because that event can easily be triggered pressing home and back to the application. I would have to use extra boolean to determine if I need to apply the smoothScroll in onResume and I don't find that personally very good coding style to handle this kind of case.